# Angle limit problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have been trying to interpret orientation angle data retrieved from a sensor device.

It returns the angle in Radian units towards North that the device is measuring at the moment.

The problem I am having right now, is that these measurements are noisy, and need some filtering, so I use a moving average of, say, 50 measurements.

But since the angles are placed in the [-$\pi$; $\pi$] interval, when approaching a direction close to the limit, the average will be affected in an undesired way: cancelling values before the lower and the upper limit.

How can I achieve a Moving Average orientation signal that isn't affected by this frequent limit transitions?

The resulting average may "jump around" due to being near the limits, as this is expected, and will end up being equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to assume the heading doesn't change too much between readings, you should just add or subtract $2 \pi$ to make the new reading be as close to the previous reading (or the current average) as possible.  If the sensor is rotating slowly clockwise the reading will slowly increase.  As it reaches $\pi$ you will start getting readings that are almost $-\pi$.  Adding $2 \pi$ will make them slightly more than $+\pi$, which is what you want.

Comment: It looks like a good approach, and the heading shouldn't change much between readings, but in the overall, it may cover every possible angle (the purpose is to track walking direction, on an athletics track), so I'm not sure this approach would work. You mean that when I read a new heading, if this new value is more distant from the average than, say, Delta, that I should add 2π?

Comment: That is right, but add or subtract $2 \pi$ (you could be transitioning from a little more than $- \pi$ to a little less (which will show up as a little less than $+\pi$).  If you are doing a mile run, with four laps, the angles will mount to $\pm 8 \pi$ depending on the direction they run.  Your other code will have to accept values outside the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: I'm still not sure on how I will do it, but assuming it is trigonometric functions, they should take values outside [0,$2\pi$[. Also, I just spoke with a friend from Robotics who had the same problem and tried your solution, but said he couldn't get very good results. I'll mark it as an answer for the time being, as I am still confident it will solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It is looking good, but now I need to find just the right DELTA value, because there are some sudden shifts I suspect are not meant to be the way they are.